# Meaning of Clique epoch

Tags: clique

Can someone explain the meaning of epoch in clique? So if my genesis file contains:

```
"clique":{
    "period": 0,
    "epoch": 0
}
```

What does it mean? As far as I understand period means the time in which it is allowed to create one block which is then set to 0 second but what about epoch?

Comment: If `period` is 0, a block will be mined everytime there is a new tx broadcasted. It could be several time per second, or once in an hour.

Answer (score 1):

There may be changes between the members of poa, such as adding or decreasing, the underlying voting code will be called to make a decision, and the variable value of this decision is only valid within a century. If a conclusion cannot be voted within this century, then Voting to be relaunched in the next century